# How do I get smooth edges with OpenGL on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Here is a screenshot that maybe makes clear what my problem is.

[image]

I'm only drawing 2D circles with OpenGL.

I already read the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512456/how-to-draw-smooth-line-with-antialias
- [How to draw a smooth circle in Android using OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47584/how-to-draw-a-smooth-circle-in-android-using-opengl?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4934367/how-to-get-rid-of-jagged-edges-in-android-opengl-es

and added the blending function. 
But nothing worked or even made a difference.

This is my renderer:

```
public class GLRendererTamago implements Renderer{


private GLTamago tama;


public GLRendererTamago(){

    tama = new GLTamago();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND); 
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_FASTEST);
    gl.glClearColor(.8f, 0f, .2f, 1f);
    gl.glClearDepthf(1f);
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0, 0, -5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0);

    tama.draw(gl);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Automatisch generierter Methodenstub
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float)width / height;
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glFrustumf(-ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 1, 20);

}
```

and this my object:

```
public class GLTamago{

private int points = 1000;
private float vertices[]={0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
private FloatBuffer vertBuff;



public GLTamago(){

    vertices = new float[points * 2];
    for(int i=0; i< points; i+=3)
    {
      double rad = 2*(Math.PI *i) / points; 

      vertices[i]=(float)Math.cos(rad);     
      vertices[i+1]=(float)Math.sin(rad);   
      vertices[i+2]=0;              
    }  

    ByteBuffer bBuff=ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length*4);    
    bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertBuff=bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
    vertBuff.put(vertices);
    vertBuff.position(0);
}

public void draw(GL10 gl){
    body(gl);
    lefteye(gl);
    righteye(gl);
    mouth(gl);
 }  

private void body (GL10 gl){
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, 0);
    gl.glScalef(2.0f, 3.0f, 1.0f); //Skalierung einstellen
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}

private void lefteye (GL10 gl){
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(1, 1, 0);
    gl.glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f); //Skalierung einstellen
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(1, 1, 0);
    gl.glScalef(0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f); //Skalierung einstellen
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}

private void righteye (GL10 gl){
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(-1, 1, 0);
    gl.glScalef(0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f); //Skalierung einstellen
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(-1, 1, 0);
    gl.glScalef(0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f); //Skalierung einstellen
    gl.glColor4f(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glPopMatrix();

}   


private void mouth (GL10 gl){
    gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glScalef(1.8f, 0.5f, 1.0f); //Skalierung einstellen
    gl.glColor4f(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f, 1.0f); 
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertBuff);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, points/2);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glPopMatrix();
}
}
```

At the edges you can see pixels...
and I have no idea how I can fix this.

I often heard to try anti-aliasing and/or shaders... but I don't have any idea how that works etc.

Comment: The term you're probably looking for is anti-aliasing.

Comment: I'm sure your missing a lot of people for the sole fact that no one wants to take the time to try your code specifically, maybe a screen shot help.

Comment: @Tetrad : i heard about the anti-aliasing thing but i don't have any idea what i shoud do with it or how i coud integrate it in my existing project.

Comment: @LukeSanAntonio : You are right! I added a screenshot at the top.

Comment: @besnep since you solved your problem you should put your solution in an answer and then mark it as resolved (you might have to wait to do so).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem with the EGLConfigChooser.

I have no idea what that is doing... but it works very fine.

I just copyed the code from here:

http://code.google.com/p/gdc2011-android-opengl/source/browse/trunk/src/com/example/gdc11/MultisampleConfigChooser.java

in a new class and made as it told me:

> To use this, call myGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(new MultisampleConfigChooser()); before calling setRenderer().

Comment: What is myGLSurfaceView?! Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827745/pagecurlmagazine-with-image-from-web